# "never did" vs "never does"

Tags: meaning, verbs, tenses

Is the following sentence grammatical? :

> Jack splits a blade of grass. He won't speak up. Never does. Tom will. Always does.

For some reason it sounds weird. I was wondering shouldn't it have been *"never did"* instead of *"never does"*?

What's the difference between the sentence above and this below? :

> Jack splits a blade of grass. He won't speak up. Never did. Tom will. Always did.

Comment: *Never did* means he's never done it before.  *Neved does* means he doesn't do so, out of practice or habit.

Comment: @J.R. So *"He won't speak up. Never does."* is something like *"He won't speak up. Never will."* ?

Comment: :^) You never know. As the saying goes, "_There's a first time for everything_." (One speaks about the past; the other, the future). That said, "[never has - never will](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHMKyWgkChk)" is not all that uncommon a construct in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Never does" and "Always does" in this context indicate that these are ongoing habits or traits that you have seen, continue to see, and presumably expect to continue into the future.

The past tense of "Never did"/"Always did" says that they were happening in the past, but does not *necessarily* mean that you expect them to continue. It may be that the person is deceased, or that you no longer know them, or that you are just not saying.

Answer (score 4):

The key here is the future tense. "He won't speak up. Never does." means: we can be sure that he will not speak up because that is his custom. The present tense here covers all the timeline: he has never spoken up and he will maintain this behaviour.

If we use the past tense, on the other hand, we lose this continuity and the sentence sounds awkward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are *narrating* this incident to someone.

In that case, you are free to choose between **"never did"** and **"never does"**.

Comment: Do you mean to say that "never does" places the narrator back into the time when the story happened, whereas "never did" places the narrator at the present time, telling a past story?

Comment: @Pacerier In case of _narration_, what you are saying is correct. But you can also say the same thing for **"never did"** as you are saying for **"never does"**.

Comment: @Pacerier: To get that meaning in the second case, I would replace the future tense with the conditional (*He wouldn't speak up*). Otherwise you are mixing tenses.

Comment: @Gorpik I have to disagree with you. Both the alternatives provided by Pracerier are absolutely correct.

Comment: @rudra: Do you mean that *He won't speak up. Never did.* expresses that the action took place in the past?

Comment: @Gorpik We are talking about a **narration** here.

Comment: So don't look at the sentences one by one. See the context of what is being said.

Comment: @rudra: Just to get things right: Pacerier asks whether *never did* places the narrator at the present time, telling a past story. I answer that, in this case, he should also use *wouldn't* instead of *won't*. And you say that I am wrong. Well, maybe you are right. In this case, I understand that the narrator is moving ahead and saying something that happens in the future for Jack and Tom, but in the past for us. Otherwise, I misunderstand the sentence completely, which can also be the case :)